# How to avoid building the code once again after adding a UDID

Tags: iphone, ipad, provisioning, udid, ad-hoc-distribution

i have a application and i usually share it through ad-hoc distribution either by sending the .app file along with the  distribution profile or by sending a .ipa file by embedding the profile to the ipa while building the code through xcode.

I have to repeat the process for each and every new UDID added ,is there any way to 
send the same build for each and every new UDID added.I wanted a way where i build the code through xcode once and send the same build along with new profile generated after adding a device's UDID.

Thank you

Comment: there is no legal way to do it, you keep adding it and building it, this going the non-jailbroken path.

Answer (score 0):

there is no legal way to do it, you keep adding it and building it, this going the non-jailbroken path.

how can this be removed, btw? this should be in the comment section instead...

Answer (score -1):

you can publish the new app on a (private) site and let users download it from there: but this will make everyone download it, like an update...
you can fololw this very detailed guide: [over the air](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/xcode/distribute-ad-hoc-applications-over-the-air-ota.html)

Comment: this does not answer the question, the asker was asking how to eliminate the process of having to rebuilt everytime a new UDID is added into the Ad-Hoc tester list. You're answer solves another issue rather than this.